# Printing Script Codes

Tags: php

I wanna print out script's codes after the output.

The script goes on different ways on the way it calls. So i wanna see it when script runs. is there any function that prints all script codes as the way it writed.

Example:

```
$foo = "bar";
$foo .= " is my bar";
function foobar()
{
// do some stuff here
}
```

i wanna see the codes just like this. is there a way to do this? without file_get_contents(), file(), readfile() functions?

Answer (score 0):

This will print and syntax highlight the source code of the current file:

```
highlight_file(__FILE__);
```

Comment: but it does not show content of included files. is there another solution?

Comment: Not really, no. You could parse the source code with [`token_get_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) to find the included files and then call `highlight_file` for them, but it's not particularly nice or easy!

Comment: Do you need to see the entire code? Or would a stack trace showing you what methods were called in what files be sufficient?

Comment: i need to see entire code. there is a complex includements all over the code. I want to see them after execution.